# Follow the cursor element

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i want to do an animation effect. When i hover on the navabar i want it to follow the cursosr for limited space. You can see the example of this page. http://a.justtestingit.com/. This is my code so far but is not exactly what i want to do. Can anybody help?

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('#cursor');

        document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
        cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: " + (e.clientY - 10) + "px; left: " + (e.clientX - 10) + "px;")
        })
        document.getElementById("navbarimg").addEventListener("mouseover",function(e) {
        cursor.classList.toggle("hover")
        })
        document.getElementById("navbarimg").addEventListener("mouseout",function(e) {
        cursor.classList.toggle("hover")
        })
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('mousemove',follow);
        function follow(){
            var nav = document.querySelectorAll('.nav');
            nav.forEach(function(nav){
                let x = (nav.getBoundingClientRect().left)+(nav.clientWidth / 2);
                let y = (nav.getBoundingClientRect().top)+(nav.clientHeight / 2);
                let radian = Math.atan2(event.pageX-x,event.pageY-y);
                let rot =(radian*(180/Math.PI)*-1)+270;
                nav.style.transform="rotate("+ rot +"deg)";
            })
        }
```

```css
body{margin:0;height:100vh;background:rgb(27,27,27);}
            #cursor{width:30px;height:30px;border:2px solid gray;border-radius:50%;position:fixed;transition-duration: 100ms;transition-timing-function: ease-out;}
            #navbarimg:before{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:tranlate(-50%,-50%);}
            #cursor.hover{width: 100px;height:100px;opacity:0.1;background-color:gray;}
            #cursor.hover1{width: 300px;height:300px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Cursor</title>
   </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cursor"></div>
            <div class="nav">
            <a href="../"><img id="navbarimg"  src="navbar.svg" alt="navbar"></a>           </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using pre-built GSAP templates.

See if this helps -

[https://codepen.io/VweMWoz](https://codepen.io/pranavraghaw1/pen/VweMWoz)

```
const tl = gsap.timeline({paused: true});

tl.from(
    ".gsap-swipe",
    {
      y: 20,
      x: 20,
      rotate: -40,
      duration: 3,
      transformOrigin: '30% 80%',
      ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1, 0.5),
    }, 0
  )
  .fromTo(
    ".swipe",
    {
      xPercent: -100
    },
    {
      duration: 1,
      xPercent: 100,
      ease: Sine.easeInOut,
      stagger: {
        each: 0.15
      }
    }, 0
  )
  .from(
    ".maskSwipe",
    {
      xPercent: -100,
      ease: Sine.easeInOut
    },
    0.4
  )
  .from(
    "#hello",
    {
      duration: 1.5,
      drawSVG: "0%"
    },
    1
  )
  .from(
    ".swoop",
    {
      duration: 2,
      drawSVG: "0%"
    },
    1
  )
  .from(
    ".line",
    {
      drawSVG: "0%",
      duration: 0.5,
      stagger: {
        each: 0.2
      }
    },
    1
  )
  .from(
    ".shape",
    {
      scale: 0,
      duration: 1.3,
      transformOrigin: "50% 50%",
      rotate: '+=random(-60, 60)',
      ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1, 0.8),
      stagger: {
        each: 0.2
      }
    },
    0.2
  );

// ScrubGSAPTimeline(tl);

let hover = document.querySelector('.js-hover');

hover.addEventListener('mouseover', playTl);
hover.addEventListener('mouseout', resetTl);

function playTl(){
  tl.timeScale(1.25).restart();
}

function resetTl(){
  tl.progress(0).pause();
}
```